# How to use the same file extension with different modes?

Tags: emacs, major-mode, minor-mode

I have files with a `.new` extension that contain LaTeX code (they are the output of a program that does things on the original `.tex` source).

In order to check them I need that they have the LaTeX syntax highlighted and that they can be opened in read-only mode to avoid introducing errors. So I put these lines in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("\\.new\\'" . read-only-mode)
                ("\\.new\\'" . latex-mode))
          auto-mode-alist))
```

But it does not work as expected because only the first mode is applied. How can I force emacs to apply both `read-only-mode` and `latex-mode` to the same file extension?

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71322/add-hooks-for-a-file-type-based-on-org-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution is to associate your file extension with a custom derived major mode:

```el
(define-derived-mode read-only-latex-mode latex-mode "LaTeX"
  "Major mode for viewing files of input for LaTeX."
  (read-only-mode 1))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.new\\'" . read-only-latex-mode))
```

The new `read-only-latex-mode` does everything that `latex-mode` does (including running `latex-mode-hook` if you're already using that), but it additionally enables `read-only-mode` after all of the parent mode's actions have taken place.

Any other code which cares about the major mode being `latex-mode` *should* already be testing that using the standard approach of `(derived-mode-p 'latex-mode)` which is still true for this new mode; so in principle this approach should Just Work.

Comment: Very elegant 

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I can really provide an answer, but here's some things to consider:

1. `read-only-mode` is a minor mode, while
2. `auto-mode-alist` is meant to turn on major modes. For major modes, it makes sense that you can have only one.
3. You can put something like `-*- buffer-read-only: t; -*-` on your first line in the file (possibly behind some comments or shebangs, depending on the file type) which would turn on read-only-mode. Maybe automate this using `auto-insert-alist` and match the `.new` filename pattern.
4. There's some good suggestions over at https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jqxgiz/how_can_i_make_some_files_automatically_readonly/ , namely try file local variables and use `find-file-hook`

Hope some of that helps.